# Project Euler #6 C++

Tags: c++

The sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers is,

```
1² + 2²+ ... + 10² = 385
```

The square of the sum of the first ten natural numbers is,

```
(1 + 2 + ... + 10)² = 55² = 3025
```

Hence the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum is `3025 − 385 = 2640`.

Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.

**They say my answer is wrong :( **

```
//Project eueler problem 6

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

unsigned int sum(int);
unsigned int sqsum(int);

int main()
{
    cout << sqsum(100) - pow(sum(100) , 2);
}


unsigned int sum(int n) // function for finding sum of n numbers
{
    return (n*(n+1))/2;
}

unsigned int sqsum(int n) // function for finding sum of squares
{
     return ((n)*(n+1)*(2*n +1 ))/6 ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pow(sum(100) , 2);` uses `double` and returns `double`, and so, you may then have rounding error.

using something like (also fix order of operand):

```
cout << sum(100) * sum(100) - sqsum(100) << std::endl;
```

should solve your issue.

Comment: I used this but the answer(4269803146) is still not correct.

Comment: @HimagraChawla You have it backwards. It should be `sum(100) * sum(100) - sqsum(100)`.

Answer (score 0):

## I think this is an easier approach :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int sum_p = 0;
   int sum_e = 0;
   for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
       sum_p=sum_p+i*i;
       sum_e=sum_e+i;
   }
   sum_e=sum_e*sum_e;       
   cout<<sum_e-sum_p;
}
```